# RadioButton.IsChecked Not Going False

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have a UWP app in C#. I have a Radio Button that the user can turn check or uncheck. It is checked by default and the user can uncheck it when they wish. However when they uncheck it the `bool` value for `RadioButton.IsChecked` never returns `false` making impossible for the user to then recheck the Radio Button if required. My code is below.

```
    private void usingmltBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (RadioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            RadioButton.IsChecked = false;
            i2cerrRec.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            i2cerrTxt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            mltI2Cnck = 0;

        }
        else if (RadioButton.IsChecked == false)
        {
            RadioButton.IsChecked = true;
            mlttempLbl.Text = "N/C";
        }

    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a checkbox for this? Radio buttons are used to select an option from a set of options. Checkboxes are for yes/no. It doesn't usually make sense to uncheck a radio button; rather, you'd be selecting a different option instead (including an option which could represent 'no selection')

Comment: Radio buttons allow the user to select one option from a set. You should use radio buttons for optional sets that are mutually exclusive if you think that the user needs to see all available options side-by-side.

If you want a single YES/NO option, use a checkbox.

Comment: you cannot unselect a radio button by clicking it. You have to add another radio button along with it. Then you can select either of them to select/unselect. Use checkbox instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other's have described, RadioButtons are designed to work in a group. This means that you will have multiple RadioButtons for a user to select from but they can only have one checked.

When a RadioButton is checked, it cannot be unchecked by the user by clicking it again without using a custom behaviour that checks if the user has tapped the RadioButton but this would not be recommended.

I suggest that you use the CheckBox for this particular functionality. You can even re-template a CheckBox control to look like a RadioButton if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the url below

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/radio-button
```

You might wrong in XAML code!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
 private void usingmltBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (RadioButton.Checked == true)
            {
                RadioButton.Checked = false;
                i2cerrRec.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                i2cerrTxt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                mltI2Cnck = 0;

            }
            else if (RadioButton.Checked == false)
            {
                RadioButton.Checked = true;
                mlttempLbl.Text = "N/C";
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems in here:

1- I might be wrong but the method you posted is triggered by a control whose name is `usingltBtn` (Not descriptive by the way) if this is the case you might be running this code with the trigger of another control.

2- Either the name of the RadioButton is `usingltBtn` or not you are not referencing the code to your control `RadioButton` is the name of a class not a specific control.

**How to fix this?** If the name of your control is `usingltBtn` use `usingltBtn.IsChecked` instead of `RadioButton.IsChecked` if not find the name of your control and use it